# My SQL script for making parent child hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a CSV file called IAB_categories which has the data similar to this table:

```
IAB1 | IAB1-1  | IAB1-2    | IAB2  | IAB2-1     | IAB2-2
Arts | Books   |  Movies   |  Auto | Auto Parts | Auto Repair
```

I want to define a parent child hierarchy so that the IAB1-1 and IAB1-2 comes as a sub category of the IAB1 category, Similarly for IAB2 the IAB2-1 and IAB2-2 should come as sub categories and so on. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review the help section on how to ask a question so that you will get useful answers, and about what types of questions are appropriate on SO. SO is not a code writing service. You will need to show that you have done some research into your problem, and what you have tried to resolve the problem. In this case, you need to explain more about what you are doing. How are you importing the data (php? myPhpAdmin?, etc.)?

Comment: What has this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: hey Strawberry, I was just wondering if there is a mysql script which will help load the data and create this parent child hierarchy.